# Unable to setup Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, centos6

I am setting up cassandra cluster on centos 6.9 but unfortunately I am not able to do it.

cassandra versiion: `3.10`

after running `cassandra -R -f`

console logs stuck at

```
INFO  [main] 2017-05-18 16:48:50,724 Server.java:156 - Starting listening for CQL clients on /192.168.22.231:9042 (unencrypted)...
INFO  [main] 2017-05-18 16:48:50,788 ThriftServer.java:116 - Binding thrift service to /192.168.22.231:9160
INFO  [Thread-2] 2017-05-18 16:48:50,794 ThriftServer.java:133 - Listening for thrift clients...
```

debug.log shows following

```
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.run(OutboundTcpConnection.java:234) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
DEBUG [MessagingService-Outgoing-/192.168.22.229-Gossip] 2017-05-18 16:54:57,313 OutboundTcpConnection.java:495 - Unable to connect to /192.168.22.229
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnectionPool.newSocket(OutboundTcpConnectionPool.java:146) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnectionPool.newSocket(OutboundTcpConnectionPool.java:132) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.connect(OutboundTcpConnection.java:397) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.run(OutboundTcpConnection.java:234) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
(END)
```

Please help.

Comment: Add route `192.168.22.229`

Comment: @Ashraful Islam: thank you for reply, can you give some hint how to add route .

Comment: Have you deployed this internally or on the cloud? And are you able to ping that ip address 192.168.22.229?

Comment: I have deployed it into two physical servers. And I am able to ping both the machines of my cluster.

Comment: This is almost certainly a firewall issue. Ensure that you are allowing all ports between each node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be the problem of firewall also.Try to stop your firewall and test again. For `centos 6` following command should work.

`service iptables stop`

Comment: You want to allow nodes through the firewall, not turn it off completely. If you do this then anyone will be able to access your database.

Comment: This is what I recommended to do quick check. If it works then only IPs of required nodes can be configured for bypass firewall permission.

Answer (score 2):

Open the firewall on each node for the other nodes.

Add these lines to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` on each node replacing NODE#_IP with the corresponding IP address:

```
-A INPUT -s NODE1_IP -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s NODE2_IP -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s NODE3_IP -j ACCEPT
```

Then restart iptables: `service iptables restart`